# Triggering the Jenkins build from any machine

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a public repository in the Github and I have configured it in the local machine and I am triggering the build.

My requirement is to trigger the build from any system for the respective project,can someone help me on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3):

Git and Jenkins trigger works on basis of git webhooks,

In github you need to add the jenkins url where its configured and it should be accessible to outside world.

So when there is change in code it sends event to jenkins to trigger the respective branch.

If you still have confusion then make question bit elaborately with specific requirement.